# Do women need to do the first-born fast for a minor son?

Tags: women, passover, fast-days, bechor-firstborn

Rema in Shulchan Aruch, 470:2 says that a father should fast for his first born (or attend a siyum) on Erev Pesach, if the son is too young to fast, himself. He also states, that if the father, himself is a first born, then the mother should fast for the son.

Let's say the father died, or for some reason, the father cannot fast for health reasons. Is the mother obligated to fast or attend the siyum for her son?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fasting for a child bechor before Passover](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27170/fasting-for-a-child-bechor-before-passover) One of the answers deals with a father who is a bechor and whether the mother should fast for the child. That should be the same situation as this question.

Comment: How is the father being unable to fast for the child due to his already fasting for himself different from any of the other cases you mentino?

Comment: @DoubleAA What?? In the SA's case, he is already fasting. My situation posits that he is NOT fasting. Or there is no father at all.

Comment: @DanF I know. Why should that difference matter? Either way the dad isn't fasting for the kid, so the mom does.

Comment: Did you try checking any commentators to the ShA there? Which? Did they say anything helpful? Including that info can help reduce redundant searching by others, wasting their time.

Comment: @DoubleAA http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27170/fasting-for-a-child-bechor-before-passover/27194#27194 cites the Rama, Mateh Moshe, Maharil, and Magen Avraham on the issue. This shows the machlokes as to whether the mother does or does not fast for the bechor.

Comment: @sabbahillel No it doesn't. It discusses a case where the father is already fasting.

Comment: @DoubleAA As you said in the comment above `Either way the dad isn't fasting for the kid, so the mom does` As a result, what the mother does would follow the same reasoning.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not seeing how you can generalize. To me, SA seems to indicate a specific situation that the father is fasting for himself; then the mother fasts. I don't see how to make a generality from just this situation.

Comment: @DoubleAA Ba'er Hetev and Magen Avraham have differing opinions, but, to me, it still seems to apply only to the case cited in SA, and not if there is no father at all.

Comment: @DanF Why would you think not to generalize? What's the relevant difference in the cases that would indicate the same solution wouldn't work?

Comment: @DoubleAA you are commenting to DanF that you should be able to generalize and to me that you should not be able to generalize. Which way are you going?

Comment: @sabbahillel That both of you should back up your assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch Harav ([470:5](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/470/5/index.htm)) writes:

> אם אין לה בעל שיתענה בעד בנו אינה צריכה להתענות אם היא מעוברת או מניקה ויש לה צער מן התענית וכן יולדת כל שלשים יום אף שאין לה צער ומכל מקום אם התענית כבר פעם אחת בעד בנה והיה אז בדעתה לנהוג כן לעולם עד שיגדל בנה הרי תענית 
>   זה עליה כנדר וצריך להתירה על ידי שאלה וחרטה
>
> If she doesn't have a husband to fast on behalf of her child, she does
>   not need to fast if she is pregnant or nursing and she will have pain
>   from fasting, and the same Din applies to a woman who gave within the
>   last 30 days even if  she suffers no pain.
>
> Nevertheless, if she fasted once in the past on behalf of her son and
>   she had in mind then to act accordingly forever until her son grows
>   up, then this fast is to her like a *neder* (vow) and she must annul
>   it through *sheilah vachrota* (the process of annulling one's vows).

(*translation mine*)